# Using Year as a filter to select a range of Dates in LightSwitch

Tags: c#, linq, parameters, visual-studio-lightswitch

In LightSwitch I would like to add a screen filter where the user selects a year (int), so the query returns all records where a specific date (DateTime) is within that year range.

I would like to understand how to add the appropriate PreprocessQuery code.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a table like this:

```
 Id        DateTimeColumn
----    -------------------
 0        1/1/2001 8:00 AM
 1        2/2/2002 8:00 AM
 2        3/3/2003 8:00 AM
 3        4/4/2004 8:00 AM
```

Add an Integer Type Data Item called `YearSelect` to the screen and create a Choice List with all the years that you want (alternatively, use a table to list all of the years). Drag this onto the screen tree and it will become an AutoCompleteBox and allow you select a year.

Create a Query in Query Designer on the above table and add a Parameter called `YearFilter`. Add this Query to the screen and bind `YearFilter` to `YearSelect`.

Back in Query Designer, click the arrow next to Write Code and select `TableName_PreprocessQuery`. Add the following code to the PreprocessQuery:

```c#
partial void TableName_PreprocessQuery(int YearFilter, ref IQueryable<Cours> query)  
{
    if (YearFilter != null)
    {
        query = from d in query
                where d.DateTimeColumn.Year = YearFilter
                select d;
    }
}
```

Now when you select a year from the AutoCompleteBox, the Data Grid on the screen that is bound to the Query should update and show only the Entities that are in the selected year.